# Twilio split based on widget storing old data

Tags: twilio

I was trying to create an IVR system using Twilio Studio. I was able to configure it using Studio, Twimlets, and Twilio functions to achieve the functionalities that I wanted.

In my IVR flow, I accept the input and in the split based on widget I check for 1 or 2 or #. If # is pressed, I replay the script with IVR options and then gather input again from the user. Now whatever is the input pressed by the user, the input is read as # by the widget and the loop continues.

My workflow is as follows:
[image: Workflow]
Looks like the value that is entered in the split_based_on widget is not getting refreshed. I am not sure if am missing any configuration here. Also in the logs, I see active executions even after the call has ended. Should I do something more to stop execution after the call is disconnected?

Comment: Can you provide a better screenshot? Your configuration is not visible. :)